# Java null pointer exception during the creating of object

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Every thing seems fine still I can't create a new object in the other class.I got just `"java.lang.Null.Pointer.Exception"`
Actually I have a F16 class which is used to create F16 aircraft.now when I try to create a new object in MainActivity to show the aircraft,this error is shown.

**MainActivity Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
    LinearLayout Map=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Map=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Map);
        try{
        F16 myF16=new F16();        
        myF16.CreateAirCraft(myF16.CoordinateX,myF16.CoordinateY, this, Map);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
        Log.d("Er", ex.toString());     
        }
    }
```

**F16 Class**

```
public class F16 extends AirCraft {
Context context;
private int Image=context.getResources().getIdentifier("F16" , "drawable", context.getPackageName());
LinearLayout PlaneBody=null;//a container used to hold All information of Aircraft
TextView PlaneName=null;// mentions to AirCraft name
ImageView PlaneImg=null;//mentions to AirCraft Image
public void CreateAirCraft(byte X , byte Y,Context Ctx,LinearLayout Map){
        Name="F-16";    
        PlaneBody=new LinearLayout(Ctx);
        PlaneName=new TextView(Ctx);
        PlaneImg=new ImageView(Ctx);
        PlaneName.setText(Name);
        PlaneImg.setImageResource(Image);
        PlaneBody.addView(PlaneName);
        PlaneBody.addView(PlaneImg);
        Map.addView(PlaneBody);
    }
}
```

**AirCraft Class**

```
public abstract class AirCraft {
   public String Name="";
   public byte CoordinateX=0;
   public byte CoordinateY=0;
   public byte Weight=0;
}
```

Comment: @Clairvoyant i have gotten just "java.lang.Null.Pointer.Exception".Nothing more!

Comment: Before posting the logs, enable stacktrace by using `Log.d("Er", ex.toString(), e);` in the catch block.

Comment: How is it possible that you getting only `java.lang.Null.Pointer.Exception` nothing more. That can't be possible.

Comment: what line you are getting the error@curiousdog

Comment: @PiyushMittal when it tries to create new object "F16 myF16=new F16();"

Comment: Post you logcat . I think your logcat throws java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: the way you are getting the image is probably wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make constructor in F16 class with context as argument
for example

```
public F16(Context context)
{
Image=context.getResources().getIdentifier("F16" , "drawable", context.getPackageName());
}
```

and from Main activity pass context

```
F16 myF16=new F16(this);
```

Comment: it seems it works becuase it shows the aircraft's name but it doesn't show the image . what do you think ?

Comment: You're missing `this.context = context;`. And now that it's initialized in the constructor, the `CreateAirCraft` method probably doesn't need to take `Context` as a parameter anymore, unless that could be a different context, of course.

Comment: where you have stored image?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
public class F16 extends AirCraft {

Context context;
private int Image;
LinearLayout PlaneBody=null;//a container used to hold All information of Aircraft
TextView PlaneName=null;// mentions to AirCraft name
ImageView PlaneImg=null;//mentions to AirCraft Image

public F16(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    Image=context.getResources().getIdentifier("F16" , "drawable", context.getPackageName());
}

public void CreateAirCraft(byte X , byte Y,Context Ctx,LinearLayout Map){
        Name="F-16";    
        PlaneBody=new LinearLayout(Ctx);
        PlaneName=new TextView(Ctx);
        PlaneImg=new ImageView(Ctx);
        PlaneName.setText(Name);
        PlaneImg.setImageResource(Image);
        PlaneBody.addView(PlaneName);
        PlaneBody.addView(PlaneImg);
        Map.addView(PlaneBody);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `NullPointerException` is caused by line 3 of the `F16` class.

```
Context context;
private int Image=context.getResources().getIdentifier("F16" , "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

Field `context` is implicitly initialized to `null`. Then `Image` is being initialized and calls `context.getResources()`, but since `context` is null, you get the NPE.

Comment: BTW: This is the answer to **why** you are getting the error. "Android Weblineindia" has answered **how to fix it**.

Comment: he is getting the error in F16 myF16=new F16(); @Andreas

Comment: @PiyushMittal He is, but the `new F16()` call executes the field initializers, and it's the initializer that's causing the NPE.